# How can I train an Alex-Net from scratch using Python?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I should train an AlexNet from scratch because the one that I was given is not good enough (actually it is not good at all). Can you recommend some script, maybe in Python that does this job. I suppose that there's something already working, I do not want to reinvent the wheel. I already have my **imageset** to train the network.

> Note:-  This is not my "homework". I'm expected to develop a Java application that uses such a network

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Keras](https://keras.io/) to do tha in python in just a few lines of code. 
Check out this example https://engmrk.com/alexnet-implementation-using-keras/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll study this page ahaha. If I'll have extra doubts can I ask you some question here?

Comment: @Luigi2405 In general, try simply goggling it or, even better, follow the keras documentation, there is plenty of resources on the topic. If you really need help you can contact me privately, my email is on my profile. Comments should not be used as a chatroom.

Comment: It's ok. It seems clear. Before long I'll give more attention to it. Just one information. At the end of the training phase how can I retrieve the .prototxt and the .caffemodel files? Basically I need them for my work

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/). This Python library offers a bunch of pretrained networks.

Typically for [alexnet](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/alexnet.html), you could proceed like so once you have installed pytorch:

```py
import torch
import torchvision.models.alexnet

model = alexnet(pretrained=False)
```